# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar los datos extraidos de una función en plsql?

Tags: funciones, plsql, function

Se tiene la siguiente función la cual da como resultado una serie de datos:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_obtener_control_tranf_ext(fechainicio DATE,fechafinal DATE)
RETURNING CHAR(11) AS cnss, CHAR(18) AS ccurp, CHAR(10) AS cfechacargadatamart,CHAR(20) AS cfecharegistrotraspaux, CHAR(2) AS ctipopension, CHAR(20) AS cfechainiciopension,
      CHAR(40) AS capellidopaterno, CHAR(40) AS capellidomaterno, CHAR(40) AS cnombre, DECIMAL(10,2) AS dpretiro97, DECIMAL(10,2) AS dpcesantiacuotaestesp, DECIMAL(10,2) AS dpcuotasocial,
      DECIMAL(10,2) AS dpsar92, DECIMAL(10,2) AS dpvivienda, DECIMAL(10,2) AS dpimportetotaltransf, DECIMAL(10,2) AS dpImporteTotalCesantiaEstEspCuotaSocial;

DEFINE cNss CHAR(11);
DEFINE cCurp CHAR(18);
DEFINE cFechaCargaDatamart CHAR(20);
DEFINE cTipoPension CHAR(2);
DEFINE cFechaInicioPension CHAR(20);
DEFINE cApellidoPaterno CHAR(40);
DEFINE cApellidoMaterno CHAR(40);
DEFINE cNombre CHAR(40);
DEFINE dpRetiro97     DECIMAL(10,2);
DEFINE dpCesantiaCuotaEstEsp      DECIMAL(10,2);
DEFINE dpCuotaSocial DECIMAL(10,2);
DEFINE dpSar92 DECIMAL(10,2);
DEFINE dpVivienda   DECIMAL(10,2);
DEFINE cFechaRegistroTrasp CHAR(20);
DEFINE cFechaRegistroTraspAux CHAR(20);
DEFINE dpImporteTotalTransf DECIMAL(10,2);
DEFINE dpImporteTotalCesantiaEstEspCuotaSocial DECIMAL (10,2);

LET cNss ='';
LET cCurp = '';
LET cFechaCargaDatamart = '';
LET cTipoPension ='';
LET cFechaInicioPension = '';
LET cApellidoPaterno = '';
LET cApellidoMaterno = '';
LET cNombre = '';
LET dpRetiro97 = 0;
LET dpCesantiaCuotaEstEsp = 0;
LET dpCuotaSocial = 0;
LET dpSar92 = 0;
LET dpVivienda  = 0;
LET cFechaRegistroTrasp = '';
LET cFechaRegistroTraspAux = '';
LET dpImporteTotalTransf = '';
LET dpImporteTotalCesantiaEstEspCuotaSocial = ''; 

FOREACH

    --NVL(to_char(max(inf.fecha_ini_pen),'%Y%m'),'') as fecha_ini_pen

    --Query principal 
    SELECT NVL(dis.nss,0), NVL(dis.curp,0),ret.fec_carga_datamart,TO_CHAR(afi.finicta,'%d/%m/%Y'),ret.tipo_pension,ret.fecha_ini_pen,afi.paterno,afi.materno,afi.nombres
    INTO cNss,cCurp,cFechaCargaDatamart,cFechaRegistroTrasp,cTipoPension,cFechaInicioPension,cApellidoPaterno,cApellidoMaterno,cNombre
    FROM dis_cuenta AS dis
    INNER JOIN ret_det_datamart AS ret ON (dis.nss = ret.nss)
    INNER JOIN afi_mae_afiliado AS afi ON (dis.nss = afi.n_seguro)
    WHERE dis.tipo_movimiento IN (800,810,815)      
    AND ret.fec_carga_datamart::DATE BETWEEN fechainicio AND fechafinal
    AND ret.tipo_tramite = '003'
    ORDER BY ret.sec_pension DESC   

    --to_char(MAX(fecha),'mdy(%m,%d,%Y)'),'01/01/0001')         
    
    --Campo retiro97
    SELECT (sum(a.monto_en_acciones * c.precio_del_dia)) As pesos
    INTO dpRetiro97
    FROM dis_cuenta AS a JOIN glo_valor_accion AS c ON(a.siefore = c.codigo_siefore) 
    WHERE a.subcuenta in (1) 
    AND a.fecha_conversion <'01/01/2022' 
    AND c.fecha_valuacion = '12/31/2021'
    and a.nss = cNss;
    
    --Campo Cesantía y vejez, Cuota estatal y Cuota Especial
    SELECT (sum(a.monto_en_acciones * c.precio_del_dia)) As pesos 
    INTO dpCesantiaCuotaEstEsp
    FROM dis_cuenta AS a JOIN glo_valor_accion AS c ON(a.siefore = c.codigo_siefore) 
    WHERE a.subcuenta in (2,6,9) 
    AND a.fecha_conversion <'01/01/2022' 
    AND c.fecha_valuacion = '12/31/2021' 
    and a.nss = cNss;
    
    --Campo Cuota Social
    SELECT (sum(a.monto_en_acciones * c.precio_del_dia)) As pesos 
    INTO dpCuotaSocial
    FROM dis_cuenta AS a JOIN glo_valor_accion AS c ON(a.siefore = c.codigo_siefore) 
    WHERE a.subcuenta in (5) 
    AND a.fecha_conversion <'01/01/2022' 
    AND c.fecha_valuacion = '12/31/2021'
    and a.nss = cNss;
    
    --Campo Sar 92
    SELECT(sum(a.monto_en_acciones * c.precio_del_dia)) As pesos
    INTO dpSar92
    FROM dis_cuenta AS a JOIN glo_valor_accion AS c ON(a.siefore = c.codigo_siefore) 
    WHERE a.subcuenta in (7) 
    AND a.fecha_conversion <'01/01/2022' 
    AND c.fecha_valuacion = '12/31/2021' 
    and a.nss = cNss;
    
    --Campo Vivienda
    SELECT (sum(a.monto_en_acciones * c.precio_del_dia)) As pesos
    INTO dpVivienda
    FROM dis_cuenta AS a JOIN glo_valor_accion AS c ON(a.siefore = c.codigo_siefore) 
    WHERE a.subcuenta in (4) 
    AND a.fecha_conversion <'01/01/2022' 
    AND c.fecha_valuacion = '12/31/2021' 
    and a.nss = cNss;
    
    --2020-01-20
    /*IF cFechaRegistroTrasp != '' THEN
        LET cFechaRegistroTraspAux = SUBSTR(cFechaRegistroTrasp,9,2) || '/'|| SUBSTR(cFechaRegistroTrasp,6,2) || '/' || SUBSTR(cFechaRegistroTrasp,0,4);
    END IF;     */
    LET dpImporteTotalTransf = NVL(dpRetiro97,0) + NVL(dpCesantiaCuotaEstEsp,0) + NVL(dpCuotaSocial,0) + NVL(dpSar92,0) + NVL(dpVivienda,0);
    LET dpImporteTotalCesantiaEstEspCuotaSocial =   NVL(dpCesantiaCuotaEstEsp,0) + NVL(dpCuotaSocial,0);    
    RETURN cNss,cCurp,cFechaCargaDatamart,cFechaRegistroTrasp,cTipoPension,cFechaInicioPension,cApellidoPaterno,cApellidoMaterno,cNombre,dpRetiro97,dpCesantiaCuotaEstEsp,dpCuotaSocial,dpSar92,dpVivienda,dpImporteTotalTransf,dpImporteTotalCesantiaEstEspCuotaSocial WITH RESUME;

END FOREACH;
END FUNCTION;
```

De qué manera puedo filtrar los resultados comparándolos con otra tabla de la base de datos? Desde mi desconocimiento intenté hacer un inner join pero no fue posible al ser una función, alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo?

---

Texto para que me deje subir la pregunta con el código, favor de ignorar. Texto para que me deje subir la pregunta con el código, favor de ignorar. Texto para que me deje subir la pregunta con el código, favor de ignorar. Texto para que me deje subir la pregunta con el código, favor de ignorar. Texto para que me deje subir la pregunta con el código, favor de ignorar.

Comment: Hola Ramon, tal y como lo explicas es dificil ayudarte sin el código que estás trabajando, si puedes colocar tu código/query será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Listo, se agregó la información del código